# PHP 5.4 & MSSQL - Wampserver

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to update my PHP, MSSQL functions to the newer ones which are supported by PHP 5.4. I have done everything and searched everywhere but I just can't get it to work.

I have installed WampServer 32 Bit to my C: drive and I have installed SQL drivers for PHP. I have made sure that the package I chose was 3.0 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and I installed them correctly. I put the 'php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' into the ext folder which is in wamp/bin/php/ext and I added the 'extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' to the php.ini file which is in wamp/bin/php.

Next I started all the services successfully and then went to my local host to find out that I was receiving this error:

`Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\launcher\Login2.php on line 11`

Further Information:

```
Running Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate 64 bit
Download Wamp Server 2 for 32 Bit
Apache : 2.4.4 
MySQL : 5.6.12 
PHP : 5.4.16 
PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4 
SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 
XDebug : 2.2.3
Running it on my localhost/127.0.0.1
Using port 8080 in Apache
Enabled pdo extensions in php.
Using the php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
Restarted Wamp several times.
```

Comment: 1) MD5 is bad for passwords; at least use a salt. But make sure to use multiple rounds. Bcrypt does this for you. 2) `sql_clean` is no good. Escape your strings. Don’t turn me into Ryan OHara, thank you very much. 3) Why are you even `sql_clean`ing the password?

Comment: Anyways, step one is to make a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` file and see whether it actually loaded the extension and where it’s trying to load extensions from.

Comment: Wait, I think I fixed it. I had previously gone into PHP extension via wamp server controls and ticked php_pdo_mssql and php_mssql but now that I have unchecked these I don't get the error anymore but rather a database connect fail. I am not familiar with the new sql server connections. Before I used mssql_connect with my host being as 'Farbod-PC\SQLExpress' do I still use this host? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I had previously gone into PHP extension via wamp server controls and ticked php_pdo_mssql and php_mssql but now that I have unchecked these I don't get the error anymore but rather a database connect fail. I am not familiar with the new sql server connections. Before I used mssql_connect with my host being as 'Farbod-PC\SQLExpress' I still use this host and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

after spending 7 hours on it, [this was the answer](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php) to connect PHP 5.4 to MS SQL server.

edit: or just use php 5.3, as that has native php mssql connectors